# Permissions denied to upload an image

Tags: php, linux, upload, permissions

For this problem:

- /foo = root path

I'm receiving the following error when attempting to upload an image:

Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/foo/image/upload/87ffdf995f6352db0d15ea44053ee2c7.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /foo/upload.php on line 26, referer: /foo

I checked the permissions of both /image and /upload and they are both 777

- drwxrwxr-x 7 777 777 4096 Apr  4 12:46 /foo/image
- drwxrwxr-x 7 777 777 4096 Apr  4 12:47 /foo/image/upload

I set these using the following command:

```
chmod -R 777 /foo/image
```

Am I missing something with permissions? I don't understand why the i'm getting this error.

Comment: Guess I'm confused, I thought 777 meant anyone could execute/upload/edit etc.

Comment: Yeah, ignore my last comment, I see you do have RW set for everyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you are setting permissions for the wrong user.
This has happened to me in the past, I was setting permissions for "MY_USER_NAME" when I should have been setting the permissions for "www-data" user.

The following links may be helpful to you:

```
http://superuser.com/questions/144984/setting-permissions-for-specific-user-and-groups-in-linux
http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml
http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Kinda hit me like a brick wall after reading 2 of them.